# DIV scroll with follow-up on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, scroll

Hi I create a local WebApp and have a Div with overflow: scroll which contains an UL list.
Now when scrolling there is no iPhone typical "follow-up". (hope this is the right word)

I mean if you scroll on an iPhone and release the finger it keeps on scrolling for a while till it stops. (scrolling slows down until 0 speed)

Does anyone know why that doesn't behave like expected?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you be more specific ?

Comment: you mean that on iphone you do not see the scroll-bar of the div?

Comment: Question is not understood!!!

Comment: I mean if you scroll on an iPhone and release the finger it keeps on scrolling for a while till it stops. (scrolling slows down until 0 speed)

Comment: Is my question more clear now?

Comment: No ideas or still not understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok by now I found myself:

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

This has to be added to the element which is set to "overflow: scroll".